# MFC: CSting IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, mfc

when I convert the int to CString, the source code is showed as following

```
int count = 0;
CString msg;
msg.Format("%d", count); // error
```

error messsage is

> IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function
>   "ATL::CStringT::Format [with
>   BaseType=wchar_t, StringTraits=StrTraitMFC_DLL
>   ATL::ChTraitsCRT>]" matches the argument list
>   argument types are: (const char [4])                object type is:
>   CString

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclose "%d" in _T()

```
msg.Format(_T("%d"), count);
```

Comment: Just to clarify: Your project settings are configured to compile with `UNICODE` defined so your string literals must be wide strings.